# Why do I have to click twice for this JavaScript function to work?

Tags: javascript, html

In order for the fucntion to change the display to "hidden" then back to "block" it requires 2 clicks for each. Why is this? How do I reduce it to just one click?

```js
function showOfferMessage() {                                        
  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.display === "block") {
        content.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        content.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="offer-row collapsible" id="'.$oid.'" onclick="showOfferMessage()">
    <div class="offer-info-item">
        <div class="offcatreview-title">
            <h3>Cat. Rating</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-cat-rating">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>'.$message.'</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're registering an event listener on every click! So your listener executes once more every time you click.

Your code fixed:

```js
                    
function showOfferMessage(element) {
    element.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = element.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="offer-row collapsible" id="'.$oid.'" onclick="showOfferMessage(this)">
    <div class="offer-info-item">
        <div class="offcatreview-title">
            <h3>Cat. Rating</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="offer-cat-rating">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content" style="display: block">
    <p>'.$message.'</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Still have to click twice the first time, since the element's display value is empty string initially (as @rayhatfield suggested in his deleted answer).

Comment: @El_Vanja fixed

Comment: ah yes, that does work, but I had that before, I put that function in an onclick function so I could execute the function on dynamically loaded content. If I put the function in the code before the DOM exists nothing happens.

Comment: Just a general note to anyone viewing this code: it'd be better to create a CSS class to control the display rather than use inline styling and then toggle the class (I understand why you'd skip that in your answer).

Comment: @DimitriBostrovich updated with a `onclick` solution

Comment: wow thats even more simple than my preview code, works perfectly. *****'s. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` event executes the `showOfferMessage() {}` function which puts an event listener on the `"collapsible"` element. Then the second click executes the contents of the eventlistener.

But first thing first, as long as you only have a single element named `"collapsible"` why try to get multiple elements. Do a `document.querySelector` and target the element using css style selectors then chain the `addEventListener` directly on that selector.

When you are querying the style like you do you get the style that was explicitly set. In your case if there has not been a click on the `"collapsible"` element no display style was set. And even though a div has a default display style of block it has not been explicitly set so `...style.display` will return an empty string -> falsy.
You have to get the implicit style with the [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method,

Like so ([codepen](https://codepen.io/andrewRmillar/pen/MWwVNqg)):

```js
document.querySelector(".collapsible").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var content = document.querySelector(".content");
  if (window.getComputedStyle(content).display === "block") {
    content.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    content.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

And I would probably use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in the event listener:

```js
document.querySelector(".collapsible").addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.target.classList.toggle("active");
  var content = document.querySelector(".content");
  if (window.getComputedStyle(content).display === "block") {
    content.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    content.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and ended up using `!==` instead of `===`:

```
if (content.style.display !== "none") {
    content.style.display = "none";
} else {
    content.style.display = "block";
};
```